# What is the "Default callback URL:" for Tumblr API v2?

Tags: python, api, oauth, callback, tumblr

Hi I am trying to use Tumblr API v2 and OAuth
http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

First I have to register an application here: http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps

But what is the "Default callback URL"? Some random URL?

I just want to write to a Python program to make some posts using command line.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So ... this was never answered? SO folks, some us _are_ in fact so stupid that we come here looking for information....

Answer (score 9):

The default callback URL is related to the [OAuth 1.0a protocol](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/dancing-with-oauth-understanding-how-authorization-works/) that Tumblr uses to authenticate your app.

As the [OAuth 1.0a specification](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/) explains:

> *OAuth Authentication is done in three steps:*
>
> *1. The Consumer obtains an unauthorized Request Token.*
>
> *2. The User authorizes the Request Token.*
>
> *3. The Consumer exchanges the Request Token for an Access Token.*

So with Tumblr process basically looks like this:

1. A Tumblr user comes to your website, where you have an app that requires some of the private information from their Tumblr account.
2. Your app will ask Tumblr for an "[unauthorized request token](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_step1)".
3. After your app receives this unauthorized request token from Tumblr, it will then redirect the user to a Tumblr login page, passing the request token along with them.
4. The user will then be [asked by Tumblr if they want to allow your app to access their account](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_step2). **Once the user accepts, Tumblr will authorize the request token, and then redirect the user to the "Default Callback URL"** (which your question refers to).
5. Your app will then [exchange this authorized request token for an "access token"](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_step3), which will enable the app to access the user's protected Tumblr data.

... Well, hopefully that clears things up a bit!

Comment: You described the process but did not clarify what to put and why. This is not clear, "and then redirect the user to the "Default Callback URL""

Comment: You _must_ have access to the callback URL. This answer is very veague in that respect. **The "authorized request tokens" are passed through the callback URL as arguments**.  (ex: `g.com?arg=val`) You need to be able to access them if you want to proceed. Which means that the callback-URL is either part of your Web-App or localhost which you can access server running on your users computer.

Comment: I still don't understand. If I'm writing a bot that just runs as a standalone process, and not a web app through which people can access Tumblr, does the callback URL matter?

Answer (score 0):

"the callback URL is the URL that a user is returned to if they logged in to Tumblr through your application."
Source: https://csc.cdf.toronto.edu/mybb/showthread.php?tid=4106

See also: http://wpweb.co.in/documents/social-network-integration/tumblr/

Answer (score -7):

I get it!
It can be a random URL.

Comment: Best answer for those of us trying to just use the API to automate our own personal interactions with Tumblr